# How to diff directories over ssh

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to recursively compare a directory in the local host to a directory in a remote linux machine. However, when i execute the next command:

```
diff -r 'ssh admin@10.0.0.10:/home/admin' /home/admin
```

it doesn't work saying:

> diff: ssh admin@10.0.0.10:/home/admin: No such file or directory

what is the right way to compare recursively the directories contents?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/59140/how-do-diff-over-ssh

Comment: this link tells how to compare files. it doesn't work in comparing dirs

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you needn't diff the detail in file, just get the difference of dir/file name, then try this:

(Note: need set "SSH login without password", for detail, review this URL:  http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)

```
diff <(ssh admin@10.0.0.10 ls -R /home/admin) <(ls -R /home/admin)
```

Comment: when ssh asks for password, it is automatically answered because of the second operator < which tunnels its output as password as follows:
diff <(ssh admin@192.168.16.139 find /home/admin -printf '"%8s %p\n"')  <(find /home/admin -printf '%8s %p\n')
This system is for authorized use only.
admin@10.0.0.1's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
admin@10.0.0.1's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
admin@10.0.0.1's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,password).

Comment: You need set non-password for SSH session first

Comment: I updated my answer, please review this URL http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Comment: Be aware, using `ls` you may run into some of the same limitations and problems with using `ls` to drive a `for` loop ( [**why for i in $(ls *.mp3) - is wrong**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) although process substitution will catch most of them

Comment: The `ls` formatting could differ on the machines. Therefore you should ensure that each file appears in a new line: `ls -1R`.

Also note that this doesn't work nicely if the base-path (here `/home/admin`) differs.

Comment: Diff command listed here gives error "Missing name for redirect" on Centos Linux.   But you can just redirect the "ls -R" output to local files and diff the local files.   I'm also using the command "find . -type f" which lists the directory and file name in one path.  Doesn't have the elegance of the above solution, but it works for me.

Comment: Also - this only works because the path of the source and destination is the same (`/home/admin`). If the paths are different you will need something like `cd $path && ls -R` instead of `diff $path`

Answer (score 38):

Try using "rsync" with the "-n" option, which just does a "dry run" and tells you what it would do.

Comment: `-c` will tell rsync to look at checksums, not just date & length

Comment: `--delete` is needful. Without it, you won't see any files that are present on the 2nd machine but not on the 1st. Make sure you have the dry run `-n` option.

Comment: of course you also need `-r` or `-a` for your recursion, and don't forget to add the backslashes after directory names (but then no star), otherwise somehow `--delete` doesn't return any deletions. so your command would be `rsync -e 'ssh -p 22' -azvn --delete admin@10.0.0.10:/home/admin/ /home/admin/`.

Comment: Another handy option: `--itemize-changes` (`-i`) will tell you for each file [what has changed](http://andreafrancia.blogspot.de/2010/03/as-you-may-know-rsyncs-delete-options.html).

Comment: Example for @FlorianBrucker suggestion:
`rsync --itemize-changes --dry-run -r -c downloads/ user@192.168.1.2:/home/user/downloads/`

Comment: @MartinH. Great. Can you please move your last comment `rsync` example into your answer ?

Answer (score 17):

You can mount the remote directory via `sshfs`, then you can use `diff -r` to compare the two directories as you want to do it.

Alternatively you could run similar `find` commands on both machines to print the file trees (e. g. file names, sizes, and dates) and then compare the outputs of both using `diff`.  This would not compare file contents, of course:

```
diff <(ssh host find /home/admin -printf '"%8s %P\n"') \
     <(find /home/admin -printf '%8s %P\n')
```

Notice the double quoting of the printf-format string in the `ssh` call.  One layer is removed by the `ssh` relay.

Comment: You might find it useful to `sort` the outputs of `find` commands before comparing them via `diff`; in that case I'd use the path as first element in the output:  `<(find /home/admin -printf "%p %s\n" | sort)`

Comment: better use %P than %p, so you can diff directories that are in a different folder on each server

Comment: Thanks @reox, I changed my answer accordingly.  Actually, I typically use this within a `(cd dir; find . -printf …)` in which case it does not make any difference whether `%p` or `%P` is used.  Here it does.

Comment: +1 for the Hint to sshfs, which allows to use the mounted Directory in an IDE like phpStorm or other Deployment Tools

Comment: @WolfgangBlessen In any case keep in mind that `sshfs` is a file system via a network and (basically) reduced to one user because whatever is done on the remote host is done with the permissions of the user who setup the underlying ssh connection.  These limitations sometimes lead to problems because some special file system features might not be properly implemented in `sshfs` and a tool like an IDE might rely on such.  In my experience, however, these situations are extremely rare.  Most problems arise from network outages (but that you could have with any network solution).

Comment: @Alfe To compare Web Installations of a Project, I now use two special ssh Users for that Application. Comparing then works fine with meld.

Comment: sshfs is horribly slow.

Comment: Not in my setup.  Maybe there is something else involved on your side (e.g. a slow or heavy loaded processor).

Answer (score 3):

Building on the answer of @MarkSetchell and the discussion underneath:

If you want to use rsync for the diff, here is an example:

```
rsync --itemize-changes --dry-run --delete --links -r -c downloads/ user@192.168.1.2:/home/user/downloads/
```

Comment: Based on https://askubuntu.com/a/918147, add `--exclude=".[!.]*"` to exclude hidden files and folders. Also you might find useful the summary of how rsync labels each change in the output https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037164/8691571, e.g. `> - the item is received`, `f - it is a regular file`, `s - the file size is different`, `t - the time stamp is different`.

Answer (score 0):

For all the examples below empty folders do not matter.

If the password is not required for `ssh` and you want to see the files

```sh
diff -y -W250 \
  <(ssh user@host1 "find /jbossas/modules -type f | xargs -I{} md5sum {} | sort -k2")
  <(ssh user@host2 "find /jbossas/modules -type f | xargs -I{} md5sum {} | sort -k2")
```

If the password is not required for `ssh` and you just want to know if the folders are the same

```sh
diff -y -W250 \
  <(ssh user@host1 "find /jbossas/modules -type f | xargs -I{} md5sum {} | sort | md5sum") \
  <(ssh user@host2 "find /jbossas/modules -type f | xargs -I{} md5sum {} | sort | md5sum")
```

If password is required for `ssh`

- Install the `sshpass` package
- Receive your password securely in the PASS variable (the password will be cleared in 60 seconds): `echo -n "Password: "; IFS= read -rs PASS < /dev/tty; trap 'unset PASS; echo "PASS has been cleared"; trap - USR1' USR1; { sleep 60; kill -USR1 $$; } &`

So...

```sh
diff -y -W250 \
  <(sshpass -p "$PASS" ssh user@host1 "find /jbossas/modules -type f | xargs -I{} md5sum {} | sort | md5sum") \
  <(sshpass -p "$PASS" ssh user@host2 "find /jbossas/modules -type f | xargs -I{} md5sum {} | sort | md5sum")
```

If `sudo` is needed on the remote host

```sh
diff -y -W250 \
  <(ssh user@host1 "echo \"$PASS\" | sudo -S find /jbossas/modules -type f | xargs -I{} md5sum {} | sort | md5sum") \
  <(ssh user@host1 "echo \"$PASS\" | sudo -S find /jbossas/modules -type f | xargs -I{} md5sum {} | sort | md5sum")
```

And you can merge the options.

I recommend [`icdiff`](https://github.com/jeffkaufman/icdiff) instead of `diff`, but `diff` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I use  `| less` at the end of the command for interactive password prompts and `sdiff` because it is easier to read than `diff` :

So between local and remote, type :

```
sdiff -s <(find $dir -printf "%p\t%s\n" | sort) <(ssh server1 find $dir -printf '"%p\t%s\n"' | sort) | less
```

and between two servers, type :

```
sdiff -s <(ssh server1 find $dir -printf '"%p\t%s\n"' | sort) <(ssh server2 find $dir -printf '"%p\t%s\n"' | sort) | less
```

where `$dir` is the full directory path you want to compare.

Answer (score -1):

I find krusader very useful for such task in case you need a GUI.
See https://www.linux.com/news/synchronize-directories-komparator-and-kdiff3 for more details http://krusador.org.

[example folder compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho7oz.png)