# Bash Local vs remote directory comparison

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to compare a local vs a remote directory and identify files which are either not present on the remote directory or different by checksum.

The goal is for the script to return a list of files to iterate through. So far I have the following, but it's not the best.

```
rsync -avnc /path/to/files remoteuser@remoteserver:/path/to/files/ | grep -v "sending incremental file list" | grep -v "bytes  received" | grep -v "total size is" | grep -v "./"
```

I've just used piped grep -v calls to remove the bits I don't care about. Is there a better way to compare a local and remote directory using SSH? It seems like their should be. The important constraint is that I have to compare directories across two separate machines.

Comment: If you want to make life even easier, take a look at [**How to diff directories over ssh**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969124/how-to-diff-directories-over-ssh)

Answer (score 1):

```
comm -3 <(ls -l /path/to/files | awk '{print $5"\t"$9}' | sort) <(ssh remoteuser@remoteserver ls -l /path/to/files | awk '{print $5"\t"$9}' | sort)
```

`$5` is size

`$9` is filename

then, print files which exists only in remote server

Answer (score 0):

I would do so using a matching pair of [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) calls and a call to [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm).

```
# comm -3 produces two-column output, skipping lines in common.
comm -3 <(find $LOCALDIR | sort) <(ssh remote@host find $REMOTEDIR | sort)
```

If you write your local and remote output to temporary files, you can easily print a list of missing files on either system; with a little cleverness in your find commands, you could likely compare file checksums between the two systems.

Note that this solution uses line-based text comparison and thus is not immune to bizarre filenames. You may need to investigate a more-clever solution (probably involving `find ... -print0`) if you need to handle filenames with newlines or other special characters.