# Upload new and modified files in folder to server with Bash

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, ftp, scp

I have a bunch of folders and files:

```
file1.txt
file2.db
file3.csv
Images/AA/BB/ABCDEFEFERFERGE/img_201553.jpg
Images/DD/CC/DFGDGDSGSFGDSGD/img_345213.jpg
Images/FF/EE/DFGSGGDSFGERERW/img_342311.jpg
```

There is about 3 files (+-1) that will get longer or smaller, as they are modified often. Then there is an Images folder with many sub folders containing images. These images will get deleted and added. They don't need to be kept in individual folders, we can put them all into 1 folder.

Every hour, I want to run a cron job that will use a bash script to copy all of this to my FTP server. If a new image is there, send it. If the 2-4 files change, send them and rename them (likely by date-time).

We can use FTP/SSH/SCP/SFTP. I don't have a preference.

Comment: This question is a bit fuzzy. What exactly is your problem? Are you looking for program libraries for FTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a folder on your localhost called `MyLocalFolder` and there's a copy of it on  remote server called `MyRemoteFolder` then you have updated `MyLocalFolder` and you need to keep contents of `MyRemoteFolder` up-to-date with `MyLocalFolder`. I think the best option in that case will be using `rsync` with an option to update (modified or new files)

`rsync -avu /path/to/MyLocalFolder/. -e 'ssh -p ssh_port' user@remote_server_ip:/path/to/MyRemoteFolder`

for more information check the man page of `rsync` command

Edit: In case you need to update the remote folder without remove files that was deleted from the local you can follow this example (and try it first to make sure its working as you expect )

MyLocalFolder contains:
file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file7 file8

MyRemoteFolder contains:
file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6

In order to update MyRemoteFolder with the new changes without removing file6:

- first list generate a list of files that exist on MyRemoteFolder and NOT in MylocalFolder using the following command:

`diff MyLocalFolder MyRemoteFolder`

this would gives you the following output

`Only in MyLocalFolder: file7
Only in MyLocalFolder: file8
Only in MyRemoteFolder: file6`

- Lets generate a list with files that only in `MyRemoteFolder`

`diff MyLocalFolder MyRemoteFolder | grep 'MyRemoteFolder' | awk '{print $4}' > dont-remove-these-files.txt`

- Pass that list to rsync to make it ignore the deleted files:

`rsync -avu --delete --exclude-from 'dont-remove-these-files.txt' MyLocalFolder/. MyRemoteFolder`

The above command will transfer modified and new files only and ignore any delete files.

I have test these steps on my local machine only and it worked correctly. but i didn't have a chance to try it with a remote server. the following url have a question about [How to use diff through ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969124/how-to-diff-directories-over-ssh) then add all necessary steps to a bash script and run it using a cron.

In case you need a backup. you can use that list again to backup the deleted files from the remote folder maybe by moving them to another folder or something.

I hope this answer is enough to get what you need.

Comment: Right, but if an image is deleted, I don't want it to delete remotely too. It has to be a backup.