# Trigger an action for just rsynced files

Tags: bash, awk, rsync

I rsync static HTML files to our webserver with this line:

```
rsync -rlpcgoDvz --delete _site/* x@xx.de:/var/www/x/public/
```

To warm up the webserver's cache I'd like to fetch the synced files right after I rsynced them. With `wget http://www.xx.de/bla/foo.html` or `curl`.

Is there a way to tell `rsync` or the `bash` shell to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in several ways, I suppose. One I came up with:

**Step 1:**
Add `--log-file` option to rsync, so you get the log of actions taken in the end. For instance:

```
rsync -rlpcgoDvz --log-file=log --delete _site/* x@xx.de:/var/www/x/public/
```

This log would look like that, for instance (log for transferring 4 files, named "file1", "file2", "file3", "file4"):

```
2015/02/13 12:52:11 [54686] receiving file list
2015/02/13 12:52:11 [54686] >f+++++++ file1
2015/02/13 12:52:11 [54686] >f+++++++ file2
2015/02/13 12:52:11 [54686] >f+++++++ file3
2015/02/13 12:52:11 [54686] >f+++++++ file4
```

We're interested in the `>f+++++++` field, and the next one which is the name of the file. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037164/782609) for a short explanation of what to expect here.

**Step 2:**

After transfer is complete, pick up the file names and call `wget` on each:

```
cat log | grep ">f++++++" | cut -d \  -f 5 | while read -r filename; do wget "http://www.xx.de/$filename"; done
```

Breaking it piece by piece:

```
cat log | \              # Pipe the file     
grep ">f++++++" | \      # Take only interesting lines.
                         # Here - only files which were not present 
                         # on the other end.
cut -d \  -f 5 | \       # Take the file name.
while read -r filename; do wget "http://www.xx.de/$filename"; done
```

You might need to adjust some file paths, etc. to fit your use case.